# Binding using a relative source and dependency property - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel

Can someone explain me the Relativesource- ancestor feature in binding with MVVM. basically a dependency property is bound to a button with the above concept thru view models. It will be great for some explanation with the samples. Or else some links would also do.

Edit 1:

```
<Button Name="button1" Content ="Edit" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" Style="{StaticResource button}"  
        Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding cMode, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource invert}}"  
        Click="EditButton_Click"  
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path= Data.User.CanEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:SCView, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
```

Also CanEdit is a dependencyproperty

Comment: Did you read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)?

Comment: I have read but i am not very clear with that ...

Comment: And what is your `DataContext`? From what I'm seeing I think, that you don't need a `RelativeSource` binding.

Comment: datacontext s set to Data in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It searches through the elements Ancestors untill it finds an element of the AncestorType. This element will be taken as Source.

In the following example the Button will have the same width as the Grid:

```
<Grid Width="100"> <!--Level=2-->
    <Border> <!--Level=1-->
        <Button Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Additionally you can set the Level where to search by setting the AncestorLevel.

Comment: Please check my edit1. In that whether the ancestor is viewmodel which is SCView ?

Comment: Try this: `Path=DataContext.Data.User.CanEdit`

Comment: hmmm...i can see some difference. what does this change mean ? i mean i didn,t get what happens with this change

Comment: I assume that the property `Data` is part of your ViewModel, which is the SCView's DataContext. You can access it via DataContext.Properties. If Data IS the ViewModel then change the line to `DataContext.User.CanEdit`.

Comment: Data is the viewmodel which is set as DataContext of SCView in the constructor.

Comment: The try `Path=DataContext.User.CanEdit` in your IsEnabled-binding.